# Parse JSON using JSON.NET VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization, json.net

I am trying to parse some JSON using JSON.NET; however, it is not something I am familiar with, and I am struggling to deserialize it.

This is the JSON:

```
{
  "disclaimer": "use at own risk",
  "license": "testing",
  "timestamp": 1391770861,
  "base": "USD",
  "rates": {
    "AED": 3.672839,
    "AFN": 56.367,
    "ALL": 103.5113,
    "AMD": 412.35,
    "ANG": 1.78894,
    "AOA": 97.608324,
    "ARS": 7.880804,
    "AUD": 1.117779,
    "AWG": 1.789825,
    "AZN": 0.784133,
    "BAM": 1.442736,
    "BBD": 2
  }
}
```

And here is my code currently:

```
Public Sub ParseJSON()
    JSONResponse = String.Empty
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(LatestURL), HttpWebRequest)
    request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    request.Accept = "application/json, text/javascript, */*"
    request.Method = "POST"
    Using writer As New StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())
        writer.Write("{id : 'test'}")
    End Using

    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Dim stream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()

    Using StreamReader As New StreamReader(stream)
        While Not StreamReader.EndOfStream
            JSONResponse += StreamReader.ReadLine()
        End While
    End Using

    Dim RateReply = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RateReply)(JSONResponse)
End Sub

Public Class RateReply
    Public rates As IList(Of Rate)
    Public base As String
    Public timeStamp As Integer
    Public license As String
    Public disclaimer As String

    Public Sub New()
        rates = New List(Of Rate)()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Rate
    Public Currency As String
    Public Rate As Decimal
End Class
```

The exception I am currently getting is:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[KTMOM.Tests.Rate]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

I believe this to be because the rates are not defined as an array in the JSON, however, I do not know how to resolve this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve the problem you need to either alter JSON format to return array as the error message suggested, or if it isn't possible define another class to represent `Rates` :

```
Public Class Rates
    Public AED As Double
    .....
    .....
    Public BBD As Double
End Class
```

then define `rates` field in `RateReplay` class as a `Rates` :

```
Public rates As Rates
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to change the Rates code to this:

Public Class Rates
    Public AED As Double
    Public GBP As Double
    Public USD As Double
    Public EUR As Double
End Class . Thanks you have saved me a lot of time here

Comment: ah, you're right it should be Double instead of Rate. Corrected my answer to prevent misleading people that see this question later.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
  Dim Rates As Dictionary(Of String, Double)
```